# Producer-Consumer Queue in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, producer-consumer

I know python and databases since several years ago.

But I want to improve my limited JavaScript knowledge. For my toy project I want to use an asynchronous queue in the web browser and use AngularJS for this.

In python there is a nice class called [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) which I used in the past.

Now I search something like this, but in AngularJS

[image: async-queue-js]

- Step 1: The in-queue pulls work-items (pink circles). Just a view json bytes.
- Step 2: The User processes the data.
- Step 3: The out-queue cares for sending the result to the server.

Why this "complicated" setup? Because I want the application to be as responsive as possible. The in-queue should pre-load some data and the out-queue should handle response communication.

An other benefit is, that with this setup the application can handle server or network outage for a period of some minutes.

The two way data binding of AngularJS which immediately updates data which the user has edited does not really fit to my question. Or I missed something. I am new to AngularJS.

The pink circles in the picture represent JSON data structures. I want to push each of them with one request to the browser.

Example:

The user sees a question, then he needs to fill out three fields. For example:

- answer: Type text
- like-this-question: integer from 1..5
- difficulty: integer from 1..5

The data should be put into the queue after the used pressed "submit". He should get the next question immediately.

**Question:**

Is there already a producer-consumer Queue available for AngularJS? If not, how to implement it?

**Update**

Sending the data from the client could be implemented with plain AJAX. The in-queue which pre-fetches the data is the more complicated part. Although both could use the same implementation. It is important that the client gets the new data with super low latency. The in-queue should be filled with up to 5 items every time to avoid that the client waits for data.

In my case it does not matter if the browser gets closed and the items in the in-queue get lost. Filling the in-queue is read-only on the server part.

I am not fixed on AngularJS. I happy to change the framework if there are good reasons.

Preserving the in-queue between browser reloads could be done with localStorage (html5)

Comment: Do you need to implement the Queue in JS or is that just your preference? Why not just use one of the manifold queues in existence and communicate with it over REST? My understanding is that AngularJS is supposed to be used in this way.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-taskqueue if you are interested in using a Task Queue API written in JS.

Answer (score 3):

Just rethinking, do you really need producer-consumer in your frontend? 
In your example, I think a simple `pub-sub` or `$Q` is good enough in this case.

example:

create a subscriber service, in your example, `questionHandlerService` which subscribe the event `question-submitted`, in your `questionService` when user submit the question, just publish the event `question-submitted` with the data, fire and forget. you don't need to wait for the response from the `questionHandlerService`.

Just keep in mind, there is only one main thread in javascript, if your method will block the ui, like `loop through 1000 items in the array, synchronous process them`, there is no help if you are put that in another "queue", because, it will must block the ui when executing unless you execute it in a web-worker. And what if user **refresh the browser**? your unprocessed request just lost.

firing an **XHR** call will not block the UI, it doesn't make sense to implement the `producer-consumer` in frontend, you can just validate the input fire the **XHR**, let backend to handle the heavy lifting, in your backend controller, you can use a queue to save the request and response immediatly. and process the queue from whatever thread or another process.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sending the data from the client could be implemented with our solution or just plain AJAX. The in-queue which pre-fetches the data is the more complicated part. It is important that the client get the new data with super low latency. The in-queue should be filled with up to 5 items every time to avoid that the client waits for data.

Answer (score 2):

> [Working Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/D3lSgBEzn3uEfvLmqzEr) - The Backend Service is used just for mocking the rest-interface; I fixed some bug such as error-limit. So, assume the Plunker as a last-version...

I haven't enough time to improve what following, but, you can assume it as a starter point...

By the way, I think that you need could be:

1. A service that wraps $http.
2. A method **push** that we will use when we'll need to register a task.
3. A recursive **private** method **_each** that, step by step, reduces the registered queue.
4. ...everything else that you think is important (getCurrentTask, removeTask, ecc.).

---

#### Usage:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['Queue'])
  .controller('MyAppCtrl', function($httpQueue, $scope) { 
    var vm = $scope;
    
    // using a route.resolve could be better!
    $httpQueue
      .pull()
      .then(function(tasks) { vm.tasks = tasks;  })
      .catch(function() { vm.tasks = [{ name: '', description: '' }]; })
    ;
  
    vm.onTaskEdited = function(event, task, form) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if(form.$invalid || form.$pristine ) { return; }
      
      
      return $httpQueue.push(task);
      
    };
  })
;
```

```html
<article ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
    
    
    <form ng-repeat="task in tasks" name="taskForm" ng-submit="onTaskEdited($event, task, taskForm)">
      <input ng-model="task.name" placeholder="Task Name" />
      <textarea ng-model="task.description"></textarea>
    </form>
    
    
  </div>
</article>
```

---

#### Module Definition

```js
(function(window, angular, APP) {
  'use strict';

  function $httpQueueFactory($q, $http) {
    var self = this;

    var api = '/api/v1/tasks';

    self.queue = [];
    var processing = false;


    //Assume it as a private method, never call it directly
    self._each = function() {
      var configs = { cache: false };
   
   
      return self
        .isQueueEmpty()
        .then(function(count) {
          processing = false;
          return count;
        })
        .catch(function() {
          if(processing) {
            return;
          }
        
          processing = true;
          var payload = self.queue.shift();
     
          var route = api;
          var task = 'post';
          if(payload.id) {
            task = 'put';
            route = api + '/' + payload.id;
          }
        
          return $http
            [task](route, payload, configs)
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.error('$httpQueue._each:error', error, payload);
              //because of the error we re-append this task to the queue;
              return self.push(payload);
            })
            .finally(function() {
              processing = false;
              return self._each();
            })
          ;
        })
      ;
    };


    self.isQueueEmpty = function() {
      var length = self.queue.length;
      var task = length > 0 ? 'reject' : 'when';
      
      return $q[task](length);
    };

    self.push = function(data) {
      self.queue.push(data);
      self._each();

      return self;
    };

    self.pull = function(params) {
      var configs = { cache: false };
      
      configs.params = angular.extend({}, params || {});

      return $http
        .get(api, configs)
        .then(function(result) {
          console.info('$httpQueue.pull:success', result);

          return result.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error('$httpQueue.pull:error', error);
        
          return $q.reject(error);
        })
      ;
    };
  }



  APP
    .service('$httpQueue', ['$q', '$http', $httpQueueFactory])
  ; 

})(window, window.angular, window.angular.module('Queue', []));
```

---

#### Handle DataLayer changes

Handling changes on data-layer (what you called in-queue), instead, is a bit more difficult task because we need to keep in sync the **last pull** with the current pull...

By the way, if you are looking for a system that has a RealTime Notification you probably should have a look on a *Socket Layer*... I suggest **[Socket.io](http://socket.io/)** because is a well-tested, industry-approved, solution.

If you cannot implement a socket layer, another solution could be a **long polling** implementation, well described [here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery/).

For simplicity, in this post, we are going to implement a simple interval that updates the current task list...
So, the previous example becames:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['Queue'])
  .controller('MyAppCtrl', function($httpQueue, $scope, $interval) { 
    var vm = $scope;
    var 
      pollingCount = 0, // infinite polling
      pollingDelay = 1000
    ;
    
    // using a route.resolve could be better!
    $httpQueue
      .pull()
      .then(function(tasks) { vm.tasks = tasks;  })
      .catch(function() { vm.tasks = [{ name: '', description: '' }]; })
      .finally(function() { return $interval(vm.updateViewModel.bind(vm), pollingDelay, pollingCount, true); })
    ;
  
    var isLastPullFinished = false;
    vm.updateViewModel = function() {
      if(!isLastPullFinished) { return; }
      
      return $http
        .pull()
        .then(function(tasks) {
          for(var i = 0, len = tasks.length; i < len; i++) {
            
            for(var j = 0, jLen = vm.tasks.length; j < jLen; j++) {
              if(tasks[i].id !== vm.tasks[j].id) { continue; }
              
              // todo: manage recursively merging, in angular 1.3+ there is a
              // merge method https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge
              // todo: control if the task model is $dirty (if the user is editing it)
              angular.extend(vm.tasks[j], tasks[i]);
            }
            
          };
          
          return vm.tasks;
        })
        .finally(function() {
          isLastPullfinished = true;
        })
      ;
    };
  
    
    
    vm.onTaskEdited = function(event, task, form) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if(form.$invalid || form.$pristine ) { return; }
      
      
      return $httpQueue.push(task);
      
    };
  })
;
```

Hope it Helps;
I don't tested it, so, could be there some bugs!

Comment: I  have not worked with recursive methods in JS yet (only in other languages). Somehow I think it is just an endless loop. Why did you use a recursive method call for _each()?

Comment: Thank you for the link to socket.io. Looks rock solid. Thanks

Comment: It isn't endless, when the length of the queue array becomes equal to **0** the promise will be resolved and the _each method will not called anymore...

By the way, I think that you should the my solution... could be useful for you!

Comment: sorry, I don't understand this sentence you wrote: "By the way, I think that you should the my solution.". What do you want to tell me?

Comment: sorry, i missed **try**, my english is bad but I'm learning!

You should try the code I posted below!

:)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into promises as they offer the async features you seem to need, possibly combined with pulling in all or some questions at init time. If you really need offline look into service workers, albeit they are limited to newer browsers

If you can't use the service workers, you could create a service (or factory) that holds all your questions or reads ahead somewhat. You'd use the $http service to try and pull in more answers, if it is not possible you use what you have until a network connection is there again.

That checking for network can just be done with the $http service by trying to get new answers (and posting answers) in a loop with $interval for example.

Comment: Service workers are too new. Sad, the browser support is not here yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers. I guess I will need a single page view. This way I can use AppCache or hold the in- and out-queue in custom JS.

Answer (score 1):

Application structure: 
2 arrays, one with questions the other with answers.

Application startup : 
Two $interval objects, one gets the first 10 questions from server. If the question buffer length is < 10 it gets new questions pushing them into the array.

The other function checks the answer array and send if the communication is available the results to the server.

When the user checks a question it's popped fron the first array and pushed in the answer array.

That's all.. the angular 2 ways data binding shows the oldest questions using a call to a function in the app like giveMeTheLatestQuestion...

Hope it helps !

Comment: I don't understand the benifit to doing this, what if user refresh the page during the period? you may just processed 5 of them. the another 5 just losted? it doesn't make sense to implement such a arch in frontend

Comment: @Sean I updated the question: In my case it does not matter if the browser gets closed and the items in the in-queue get lost. Filling the in-queue is read-only on the server part.

Comment: @MatteoConta thank you for your answer. Your answer describes an algorithm which I could use for implementing. Is my idea really that strange, that there is no re-usable stuff available?

Comment: @Sean using 2 timers with a short interval may limit the problem if the user refreshes the page. A full page reload is a problem for every architecture in my opinion, you need to implement a server side session in order to limit this kind of problems. Guettli thanks for your answer, I would write the code from scratch,  I don't know if a library or framework may help you ot may complicate the solution.

Comment: @guettli, look at this article, it may be useful in your project https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises

Comment: @all... using a message ID you can keep track in the server of the last resolved item (when receiving a post request), at initialization ("reconnect") the client side is given the last ID to start polling. If you don't want the user to see repeated items (after a reconnect) you can keep the out-queue in a browser db.